# How to merge two ".ics" files in to one?

Tags: php, icalendar

im getting ics files from multiple sources. what i want to do is merge those two files using PHP, but i have no idea how to merge those two files. ?

this is first sample file.

```
BEGIN:VCALENDAR
VERSION:2.0
CALSCALE:GREGORIAN
PRODID:-//HomeAway.com, Inc.//EN
BEGIN:VEVENT
UID:e753a377-cc46-403f-a192-c25990400c0e
DTSTAMP:20161222T071905Z
DTSTART:20160728
DTEND:20160731
SUMMARY:Reserved - Janna Stotz
END:VEVENT
BEGIN:VEVENT
UID:989df323-1c44-4d95-ada7-e738dafa0590
DTSTAMP:20161222T071905Z
DTSTART:20170227
DTEND:20170304
SUMMARY:Reserved - Douglas Lawson
END:VEVENT
BEGIN:VEVENT
UID:3d997ba7-8aee-4836-a159-99d79eaf8f73
DTSTAMP:20161222T071905Z
DTSTART:20170213
DTEND:20170220
SUMMARY:Reserved - Stephen Harrison
END:VEVENT
BEGIN:VEVENT
UID:98a31bee-d25e-43a3-a5a4-9d443ea43b22
DTSTAMP:20161222T071905Z
DTSTART:20161222
DTEND:20161227
SUMMARY:Reserved - John Albert
END:VEVENT
END:VCALENDAR
```

this is second file below:

```
    BEGIN:VCALENDAR
    PRODID;X-RICAL-TZSOURCE=TZINFO:-//Airbnb Inc//Hosting Calendar 0.8.8//EN
    CALSCALE:GREGORIAN
    VERSION:2.0
    BEGIN:VEVENT
    DTEND;VALUE=DATE:20160720
    DTSTART;VALUE=DATE:20160716
    UID:cn31z4tbyhod--eusv3c9eu9i0@airbnb.com
    DESCRIPTION:CHECKIN: 07/16/2016\nCHECKOUT: 07/20/2016\nNIGHTS: 4\nPHONE: 
     +1 (619) 247-5942\nEMAIL: (no email alias available)\nPROPERTY: Tropical
      Retreat- 1.5 mi to Las Olas Blvd & Beach\n
    SUMMARY:Trevonne Pinckney (DA85Z5)
    LOCATION:Tropical Retreat- 1.5 mi to Las Olas Blvd & Beach
    END:VEVENT
    BEGIN:VEVENT
    DTEND;VALUE=DATE:20160724
    DTSTART;VALUE=DATE:20160722
    UID:cn31z4tbyhod-fz1hn0cqi6yg@airbnb.com
    DESCRIPTION:CHECKIN: 07/22/2016\nCHECKOUT: 07/24/2016\nNIGHTS: 2\nPHONE: 
     +1 (239) 898-9784\nEMAIL: (no email alias available)\nPROPERTY: Tropical
      Retreat- 1.5 mi to Las Olas Blvd & Beach\n
    SUMMARY:Darren Gooden (CQEBTT)
    LOCATION:Tropical Retreat- 1.5 mi to Las Olas Blvd & Beach
    END:VEVENT
    BEGIN:VEVENT
    DTEND;VALUE=DATE:20160803
    DTSTART;VALUE=DATE:20160731
    UID:cn31z4tbyhod-1y3w3tplq0zu@airbnb.com
    DESCRIPTION:CHECKIN: 07/31/2016\nCHECKOUT: 08/03/2016\nNIGHTS: 3\nPHONE: 
     +1 (610) 360-6633\nEMAIL: (no email alias available)\nPROPERTY: Tropical
      Retreat- 1.5 mi to Las Olas Blvd & Beach\n
    SUMMARY:Chad Opdyke (DFDNMN)
    LOCATION:Tropical Retreat- 1.5 mi to Las Olas Blvd & Beach
    END:VEVENT
    BEGIN:VEVENT
    DTEND;VALUE=DATE:20160808
    DTSTART;VALUE=DATE:20160805
    UID:cn31z4tbyhod--h72i8aomz756@airbnb.com
    DESCRIPTION:CHECKIN: 08/05/2016\nCHECKOUT: 08/08/2016\nNIGHTS: 3\nPHONE: 
     +1 (954) 639-3714\nEMAIL: (no email alias available)\nPROPERTY: Tropical
      Retreat- 1.5 mi to Las Olas Blvd & Beach\n
    SUMMARY:Shay Walsh (5XBTTH)
    LOCATION:Tropical Retreat- 1.5 mi to Las Olas Blvd & Beach
    END:VEVENT
    BEGIN:VEVENT
    DTEND;VALUE=DATE:20160815
    DTSTART;VALUE=DATE:20160808
    UID:cn31z4tbyhod-mac5tl2dw3eo@airbnb.com
    DESCRIPTION:CHECKIN: 08/08/2016\nCHECKOUT: 08/15/2016\nNIGHTS: 7\nPHONE: 
     +1 (929) 363-8190\nEMAIL: (no email alias available)\nPROPERTY: Tropical
      Retreat- 1.5 mi to Las Olas Blvd & Beach\n
    SUMMARY:Akeem Feiton (WYCZSJ)
    LOCATION:Tropical Retreat- 1.5 mi to Las Olas Blvd & Beach
    END:VEVENT
    BEGIN:VEVENT
    DTEND;VALUE=DATE:20160821
    DTSTART;VALUE=DATE:20160819
    UID:cn31z4tbyhod-lafyl609ekpi@airbnb.com
    DESCRIPTION:CHECKIN: 08/19/2016\nCHECKOUT: 08/21/2016\nNIGHTS: 2\nPHONE: 
     +1 (646) 523-7594\nEMAIL: (no email alias available)\nPROPERTY: Tropical
      Retreat- 1.5 mi to Las Olas Blvd & Beach\n
    SUMMARY:Walter Fox (HZA2CZ)
    LOCATION:Tropical Retreat- 1.5 mi to Las Olas Blvd & Beach
    END:VEVENT
    BEGIN:VEVENT
    DTEND;VALUE=DATE:20160829
    DTSTART;VALUE=DATE:20160826
    UID:cn31z4tbyhod--ays9sq2g0gtg@airbnb.com
    DESCRIPTION:CHECKIN: 08/26/2016\nCHECKOUT: 08/29/2016\nNIGHTS: 3\nPHONE: 
     +1 (754) 246-2940\nEMAIL: (no email alias available)\nPROPERTY: Tropical
      Retreat- 1.5 mi to Las Olas Blvd & Beach\n
    SUMMARY:Tamika Jones (ADCFN8)
    LOCATION:Tropical Retreat- 1.5 mi to Las Olas Blvd & Beach
    END:VEVENT
    BEGIN:VEVENT
    DTEND;VALUE=DATE:20161008
    DTSTART;VALUE=DATE:20161005
    UID:cn31z4tbyhod--qkhp871f4c32@airbnb.com
    DESCRIPTION:CHECKIN: 10/05/2016\nCHECKOUT: 10/08/2016\nNIGHTS: 3\nPHONE: 
     +1 (425) 891-5016\nEMAIL: (no email alias available)\nPROPERTY: Tropical
      Retreat- 1.5 mi to Las Olas Blvd & Beach\n
    SUMMARY:Shawn Woods (TSJJCD)
    LOCATION:Tropical Retreat- 1.5 mi to Las Olas Blvd & Beach
    END:VEVENT
    BEGIN:VEVENT
    DTEND;VALUE=DATE:20161105
    DTSTART;VALUE=DATE:20161102
    UID:cn31z4tbyhod-j79p4h76jnxy@airbnb.com
    DESCRIPTION:CHECKIN: 11/02/2016\nCHECKOUT: 11/05/2016\nNIGHTS: 3\nPHONE: 
     +1 (281) 710-7868\nEMAIL: (no email alias available)\nPROPERTY: Tropical
      Retreat- 1.5 mi to Las Olas Blvd & Beach\n
    SUMMARY:Glenn Gilbert (94FNJS)
    LOCATION:Tropical Retreat- 1.5 mi to Las Olas Blvd & Beach
    END:VEVENT
    BEGIN:VEVENT
    DTEND;VALUE=DATE:20161110
    DTSTART;VALUE=DATE:20161105
    UID:cn31z4tbyhod-z0uoqh0ijg0k@airbnb.com
    DESCRIPTION:CHECKIN: 11/05/2016\nCHECKOUT: 11/10/2016\nNIGHTS: 5\nPHONE: 
     +1 (830) 456-1207\nEMAIL: (no email alias available)\nPROPERTY: Tropical
      Retreat- 1.5 mi to Las Olas Blvd & Beach\n
    SUMMARY:Meredith Clements (8CHB29)
    LOCATION:Tropical Retreat- 1.5 mi to Las Olas Blvd & Beach
    END:VEVENT
    BEGIN:VEVENT
    DTEND;VALUE=DATE:20161118
    DTSTART;VALUE=DATE:20161111
    UID:cn31z4tbyhod--5el3occjewuc@airbnb.com
    DESCRIPTION:CHECKIN: 11/11/2016\nCHECKOUT: 11/18/2016\nNIGHTS: 7\nPHONE: 
     +1 (925) 519-0481\nEMAIL: (no email alias available)\nPROPERTY: Tropical
      Retreat- 1.5 mi to Las Olas Blvd & Beach\n
    SUMMARY:Charles Delmolino (ZERBWC)
    LOCATION:Tropical Retreat- 1.5 mi to Las Olas Blvd & Beach
    END:VEVENT
    BEGIN:VEVENT
    DTEND;VALUE=DATE:20161129
    DTSTART;VALUE=DATE:20161124
    UID:cn31z4tbyhod--4m4p1x5hmon2@airbnb.com
    DESCRIPTION:CHECKIN: 11/24/2016\nCHECKOUT: 11/29/2016\nNIGHTS: 5\nPHONE: 
     +1 (917) 543-5718\nEMAIL: scott-6e0gjexnbdo3gktl@guest.airbnb.com\nPROPE
     RTY: Tropical Retreat- 1.5 mi to Las Olas Blvd & Beach\n
    SUMMARY:Scott Reale (5BWZC4)
    LOCATION:Tropical Retreat- 1.5 mi to Las Olas Blvd & Beach
    END:VEVENT
    BEGIN:VEVENT
    DTEND;VALUE=DATE:20161205
    DTSTART;VALUE=DATE:20161202
    UID:cn31z4tbyhod-hhhkyes8uijs@airbnb.com
    DESCRIPTION:CHECKIN: 12/02/2016\nCHECKOUT: 12/05/2016\nNIGHTS: 3\nPHONE: 
     +1 (914) 960-7912\nEMAIL: lindsay-lnnahjxv7mtalxj7@guest.airbnb.com\nPRO
     PERTY: Tropical Retreat- 1.5 mi to Las Olas Blvd & Beach\n
    SUMMARY:Lindsay Klein (9D8PJ8)
    LOCATION:Tropical Retreat- 1.5 mi to Las Olas Blvd & Beach
    END:VEVENT
    BEGIN:VEVENT
    DTEND;VALUE=DATE:20170102
    DTSTART;VALUE=DATE:20161226
    UID:cn31z4tbyhod-oou2j35paua6@airbnb.com
    DESCRIPTION:CHECKIN: 12/26/2016\nCHECKOUT: 01/02/2017\nNIGHTS: 7\nPHONE: 
     +506 8 868 9215\nEMAIL: adriana-70yuldfuvz6exlda@guest.airbnb.com\nPROPE
     RTY: Tropical Retreat- 1.5 mi to Las Olas Blvd & Beach\n
    SUMMARY:Adriana Quiros (NE3RFN)
    LOCATION:Tropical Retreat- 1.5 mi to Las Olas Blvd & Beach
    END:VEVENT
    BEGIN:VEVENT
    DTEND;VALUE=DATE:20170111
    DTSTART;VALUE=DATE:20170104
    UID:cn31z4tbyhod-firr1585xa7w@airbnb.com
    DESCRIPTION:CHECKIN: 01/04/2017\nCHECKOUT: 01/11/2017\nNIGHTS: 7\nPHONE: 
     +1 (514) 927-4600\nEMAIL: marcel-rwupwcvc6d6vv556@guest.airbnb.com\nPROP
     ERTY: Tropical Retreat- 1.5 mi to Las Olas Blvd & Beach\n
    SUMMARY:Marcel Groleau (9HRSXZ)
    LOCATION:Tropical Retreat- 1.5 mi to Las Olas Blvd & Beach
    END:VEVENT
    BEGIN:VEVENT
    DTEND;VALUE=DATE:20170121
    DTSTART;VALUE=DATE:20170117
    UID:cn31z4tbyhod-qyvl6rznyesq@airbnb.com
    DESCRIPTION:CHECKIN: 01/17/2017\nCHECKOUT: 01/21/2017\nNIGHTS: 4\nPHONE: 
     +1 (505) 321-9458\nEMAIL: sergio-23nza8uyfzu8sb98@guest.airbnb.com\nPROP
     ERTY: Tropical Retreat- 1.5 mi to Las Olas Blvd & Beach\n
    SUMMARY:Sergio Tirado (RM54BM)
    LOCATION:Tropical Retreat- 1.5 mi to Las Olas Blvd & Beach
    END:VEVENT
    BEGIN:VEVENT
    DTEND;VALUE=DATE:20170305
    DTSTART;VALUE=DATE:20170216
    UID:cn31z4tbyhod--7eof74b6h3q6@airbnb.com
    DESCRIPTION:CHECKIN: 02/16/2017\nCHECKOUT: 03/05/2017\nNIGHTS: 17\nPHONE:
      +33 6 76 04 11 95\nEMAIL: bernard-1x4rpabhk5j9yzs3@guest.airbnb.com\nPR
     OPERTY: Tropical Retreat- 1.5 mi to Las Olas Blvd & Beach\n
    SUMMARY:Bernard Elmalem (K5MF5W)
    LOCATION:Tropical Retreat- 1.5 mi to Las Olas Blvd & Beach
    END:VEVENT
    BEGIN:VEVENT
    DTEND;VALUE=DATE:20160711
    DTSTART;VALUE=DATE:20160708
    UID:-sg3p5bpek2gn-x055w817b23p@airbnb.com
    SUMMARY:Not available
    END:VEVENT
    BEGIN:VEVENT
    DTEND;VALUE=DATE:20160725
    DTSTART;VALUE=DATE:20160724
    UID:-sg3p5bpek2gn-xobd7jo6cv1t@airbnb.com
    SUMMARY:Not available
    END:VEVENT
    BEGIN:VEVENT
    DTEND;VALUE=DATE:20160731
    DTSTART;VALUE=DATE:20160728
    UID:-sg3p5bpek2gn-24l1rot6mqtt@airbnb.com
    SUMMARY:Not available
    END:VEVENT
    BEGIN:VEVENT
    DTEND;VALUE=DATE:20160819
    DTSTART;VALUE=DATE:20160816
    UID:-sg3p5bpek2gn--pih0m6c16ygf@airbnb.com
    SUMMARY:Not available
    END:VEVENT
    BEGIN:VEVENT
    DTEND;VALUE=DATE:20160823
    DTSTART;VALUE=DATE:20160822
    UID:-sg3p5bpek2gn--47s532pniut7@airbnb.com
    SUMMARY:Not available
    END:VEVENT
    BEGIN:VEVENT
    DTEND;VALUE=DATE:20160925
    DTSTART;VALUE=DATE:20160829
    UID:-sg3p5bpek2gn--7tcr0ezisq1j@airbnb.com
    SUMMARY:Not available
    END:VEVENT
    BEGIN:VEVENT
    DTEND;VALUE=DATE:20161003
    DTSTART;VALUE=DATE:20160929
    UID:-sg3p5bpek2gn-w06qr66c509x@airbnb.com
    SUMMARY:Not available
    END:VEVENT
    BEGIN:VEVENT
    DTEND;VALUE=DATE:20161005
    DTSTART;VALUE=DATE:20161004
    UID:-sg3p5bpek2gn--ixkq49h4tbs3@airbnb.com
    SUMMARY:Not available
    END:VEVENT
    BEGIN:VEVENT
    DTEND;VALUE=DATE:20161024
    DTSTART;VALUE=DATE:20161008
    UID:-sg3p5bpek2gn--gtx4mmcry3sv@airbnb.com
    SUMMARY:Not available
    END:VEVENT
    BEGIN:VEVENT
    DTEND;VALUE=DATE:20161102
    DTSTART;VALUE=DATE:20161025
    UID:-sg3p5bpek2gn-cylycusbl2jh@airbnb.com
    SUMMARY:Not available
    END:VEVENT
    BEGIN:VEVENT
    DTEND;VALUE=DATE:20161130
    DTSTART;VALUE=DATE:20161129
    UID:-sg3p5bpek2gn--yx25kuc3pp67@airbnb.com
    SUMMARY:Not available
    END:VEVENT
    BEGIN:VEVENT
    DTEND;VALUE=DATE:20170128
    DTSTART;VALUE=DATE:20170122
    UID:-sg3p5bpek2gn--34z0d6olbk3f@airbnb.com
    SUMMARY:FlipKey reservation (Andy Vitrone). Move from 628 to 632A.
    END:VEVENT
    BEGIN:VEVENT
    DTEND;VALUE=DATE:20171223
    DTSTART;VALUE=DATE

:20171222
UID:-sg3p5bpek2gn-4mjfwyuewkk1@airbnb.com
SUMMARY:Not available
END:VEVENT
END:VCALENDAR
```

=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=

My Bad, i did not explained whole scenario.
Why i want to merge two ics, is because, i am using wordpress with icalendar.
and i get reservation dates from different sites like "Airbnb".

but when wordpress import first calendar, and after that i import second calendar, it overrides the first one.

So what i am trying to do.. is merge calendar events and then import all the events all together.

Here is the PHP Code so far for iCalendar.php.

i have edited this code, tried to do foreach loop and used and moved process to another extended function for processing.

```
function wpestate_import_calendar_feed_listing($prop_id){
    $property_icalendar_import =   get_post_meta($prop_id, 'property_icalendar_import', true);
    $property_icalendar_import2 =   get_post_meta($prop_id, 'property_icalendar_import2', true);
    $iCalURLS = array(
        'property_icalendar_import' => $property_icalendar_import,
        'property_icalendar_import2' => $property_icalendar_import2
    );
    wpestate_import_calendar_feed_listing_extend($prop_id, $iCalURLS);
//    wpestate_import_calendar_feed_listing_extend($prop_id, $property_icalendar_import2);


}

function wpestate_import_calendar_feed_listing_extend($prop_id,$iCalURLS){


    if(!intval($prop_id)){
        exit();
    }


    if(empty($iCalURLS) || !is_array($iCalURLS) || (empty($iCalURLS['property_icalendar_import']) and empty($iCalURLS['property_icalendar_import2']))){
        return;
    }

    //Validate the URLS,only if they are not empty.
    foreach($iCalURLS as $iCalURL){
        if(!empty($iCalURL)){
            if (filter_var($iCalURL, FILTER_VALIDATE_URL) === FALSE) {
                return;
            }
        }
    }

    foreach($iCalURLS as $iCalURL){

    }

    $ical   = new ICal($iCalURLS['property_icalendar_import']);
    $ical   = new ICal($property_icalendar_import);

    $events = $ical->events();
    $date = $events[0]['DTSTART'];



    if (!is_array($events)){
        return;
    }

    wpestate_clear_ical_imported($prop_id);


    //DTSTART which sets a starting time, and a DTEND which sets an ending time.
    foreach ($events as $event) {
        $unix_time_start    ='';
        $unix_time_end      ='';
        if( isset($event['UID']) ){
            $uid                =$event['UID'];

        }else{
            $uid=   esc_html__('external','wpestate');
        }


        if( isset($event['DTSTART']) ){
            //  echo "DTSTART: ".$event['DTSTART']." - UNIX-Time: ".$ical->iCalDateToUnixTimestamp($event['DTSTART'])."<br/>";
            $unix_time_start =$ical->iCalDateToUnixTimestamp($event['DTSTART']);
        }

        if( isset($event['DTEND']) ){
            //echo "DTEND: ".$event['DTEND']."<br/>";
            $unix_time_end =$ical->iCalDateToUnixTimestamp($event['DTEND']);
       }

        /*
        if( isset($event['SUMMARY']) ){
         echo "SUMMARY: ".$event['SUMMARY']."<br/>";
        }

        if( isset($event['DTSTAMP']) ){
            echo "DTSTAMP: ".$event['DTSTAMP']."<br/>";
        }

        if( isset($event['UID']) ){
            echo "UID: ".$event['UID']."<br/>";
        }

        if( isset($event['CREATED']) ){
            echo "CREATED: ".$event['CREATED']."<br/>";
        }

        if( isset($event['DESCRIPTION']) ){
        echo "DESCRIPTION: ".$event['DESCRIPTION']."<br/>";
        }

        if( isset($event['LAST-MODIFIED']) ){
            echo "LAST-MODIFIED: ".$event['LAST-MODIFIED']."<br/>";
        }

        if( isset($event['LOCATION']) ){
            echo "LOCATION: ".$event['LOCATION']."<br/>";
        }

        if( isset($event['SEQUENCE']) ){
            echo "SEQUENCE: ".$event['SEQUENCE']."<br/>";
        }

        if( isset($event['STATUS']) ){
            echo "STATUS: ".$event['STATUS']."<br/>";
        }

        if( isset($event['TRANSP']) ){
            echo "TRANSP: ".$event['TRANSP']."<br/>";
        }

        echo "<hr/>";

        */

       // print $unix_time_start." / ".$unix_time_end." / ".$uid." </br>";
        if( $unix_time_start!='' && $unix_time_end!='' && $uid !=''){
            wpestate_insert_booking_external_event($prop_id, $unix_time_start,$unix_time_end,$uid);
        }
    }

   // $reservation_array = get_post_meta($prop_id, 'booking_dates',true);
    //print_R($reservation_array);
}
```

Comment: What if you take the events from 1 file and add them to the second one?

Comment: what have you tried so far? Strip the last line from the first file, and the first 4 lines from the second file, and then write the rest of it out to a new one. The logic is not difficult, unless you have more complex (and unstated) requirements like looking for duplicate events or something. Your rep level suggests you have got enough skill to work out how to read and write files.

Comment: @ADyson
Im Actually using Icalendar in Wordpress.
What i have tried so far, using the existing the function of wordpress imported the second file, but it replaces the values of first.
I however searched the net, and i came across something similar here.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27239722/sync-multiple-icalendars-airbnb-flipkey-google-calendar-etc
But not sure if its the right way to do it :(

Comment: ok. that was not clear at all from the question, it looked like you just wanted to do some text processing. What will you do with the merged ics file? It is available for a user to sync their calendar to? I can't say if that solution works for you, as I don't really know your requirements. In the general area of calendar sync, I once came across this (commercial) API service which supposedly syncs lots of calendars: https://www.cronofy.com/ - I haven't used it but it looks interesting.

Comment: @ADyson
I have updated my question to make it more clear.

Comment: is it a specific plugin for wordpress? If so, which one?